# Find the tmux pane that has a certain directory in the directory stack

Tags: tmux

Sometimes I will lose track of what pane relates to a certain project that I'm working on. This happens most often when I `cd` out of a project directory and then let the keyboard get cold for an extended period of time. Going through the session list (`C-B s`) isn't helpful because the directory I'm looking for isn't in the working directories that are displayed.

Is there a way to find which pane has a directory stored in its shell's directory stack (`dirs`) without searching for it manually? That is, without switching to a pane, running `dirs` and piping to grep, then switching to the next pane...wash/rinse/repeat.

I'm running `zsh` with `autopushd` set.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something by configuring zsh to use
`cdr` to maintain a list of previous directories in a file rather than the
`dirstack` array used by `pushd` and so on.

From `man zshall` section *REMEMBERING RECENT DIRECTORIES*, you install the
hook:

```
autoload -Uz chpwd_recent_dirs cdr add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook chpwd chpwd_recent_dirs
```

and configure in variable `recent-dirs-file` the name of the file to save
the list in. By using:

```
zstyle ':chpwd:*' recent-dirs-file ~/.chpwd-recent-dirs-${TTY##*/} +
```

you will get a separate file for each tty.

So to search for a directory, grep through these files, and extract the tty
name from the filename that matches, then ask tmux to switch to that tty. I
am neither a zsh user, nor a tmux user, so this is just speculative, and
you may need to post new questions (rather than comments here) for help on
how to really implement this.